# react-scrollable-feed not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

im using react to build a chat windows and obviously that chat window needs to automatically scroll down so you always see the latest message at the bottom of the feed, so i found react-scrollable-feed which is supposed to do that but for some reason its not.

there are no error being shown or anything like that, I just followed the documentation,

this is the part of code where its being used:

```
import ScrollableFeed from 'react-scrollable-feed';

 return (
        <div className="chat_window_cont">

            <div>
                <ScrollableFeed>
                    {messages.map((msg, index) => {
                        if (msg.type === 'text') {
                            return (
                                <SenderMessage text={msg.text} timestamp={msg.timestamp} key={index}/>
                            );
                        } else if (msg.type === 'file') {
                            return (
                                <FileMessage file={msg.file} timestamp={msg.timestamp} key={index} />
                            );
                        }
                        
                    })}
                </ScrollableFeed>      
            </div>
    );
```

in case you are thinking that some CSS is conflicting with it, this is the CSS for chat_window_cont div:

```
.chat_window_cont {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5% 2% 0% 0%;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.chat_window_cont::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

just some normal styles and something to hide the scroll bar because i dont want it to be visible.

hopefully someone has the answer to this.
thanks in advance.

followed the documentaion step by step but didnt get any of the expected results